# Pandas Dataframe get minimum difference between two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

### Dataframe

```
d = {'Resource': ['A','A','A','B','B','B'], 'User': ['1','2','3','4','5','6'], 'earliestSlot': [1,2,3,5,4,6], 'latestSlot': [1.2,2.5,3.9,6,5,6.1]}
pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to aggregate the data in a way that calculates the minimum difference between latestSlot and earliestSlot of different users of the same resource. Basically I want to calculate the minimum idle time of each resource before the next user accesses it.

### Target Data

| Resource | MinHeadway |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0.5 |
| B | 0 |

I have the following code but I am sure there is a faster method.

´´´

```
def get_min_headway(resource_id):
    latestSlots = d[d['Resource'] == resource_id].latestSlot
    earliestSlots = d[d['Resource'] == resource_id].earliestSlot
    min_headway = float('inf')
    for time in latestSlots:
        headways = earliestSlots - time
        for headway in headways:
            if headway >= 0:
                if headway < min_headway:
                    min_headway = headway
    return min_headway

d['min_headway'] = d['Resource'].apply(get_min_headway)
```

´´´

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't understand. Why precisely should the first value of `MinHeadway` be `0.5`?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what your desired outcome is, but by *minimum idle time*, I assumed you wanted the minimum difference between "latestSlot" of the previous user and the "earliestSlot" of the next user (since an unused time is an *idle time*). So in that case, you can use the following.

We sort by "earliestSlot"; then `groupby` "Resource" and do exactly what's explained above.

```
out = (df.sort_values(by='earliestSlot')
       .groupby('Resource')
       .apply(lambda x: (x['earliestSlot']-x['latestSlot'].shift()).min())
       .reset_index()
       .rename(columns={0:'MinHeadway'}))
```

Output:

```
  Resource  MinHeadway
0        A         0.5
1        B         0.0
```

The same result could also be obtained without applying a lambda:

```
tmp = df.sort_values(by='earliestSlot')
out = (tmp.groupby('Resource')['latestSlot'].shift()
       .rsub(tmp['earliestSlot'])
       .groupby(x['Resource']).min()
       .reset_index()
       .rename(columns={0:'MinHeadway'}))
```